# XSLT Only keep topmost attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have created an XML diff but the diff is unclean in that it sometimes marks both the parent but also some of the children as changed.

I would like to clean up the diff so that only the topmost marked element keeps the diff attribute.

In the example below, I only want to keep the `diff:delete` attribute on the `<preface>` element, but remove it from all children of `<preface>`, since `<preface>` is already marked.

The input is Docbook and arbitrary elements can contain diff attributes.

Here is my XML:

```xml
<book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:diff="http://namespaces.shoobx.com/diff" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="5.0">
  <title>
    <emphasis role="uppercase">Regulation</emphasis>
(EU) 2017/745
    <emphasis role="uppercase">of the European Parliament and of the Council</emphasis>
    of
    <date>5 April 2017</date>
    on medical devices, amending Directive 2001/83/EC, Regulation (EC) No 178/2002 and Regulation (EC) No 1223/2009 and repealing Council Directives 90/385/EEC and 93/42/EEC(Text with EEA relevance)
  </title>
  <preface diff:delete="">
    <info diff:delete="">
      <title>Preamble</title>
    </info>
    <para diff:delete="">THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND THE COUNCIL OF THE EUROPEAN UNION,</para>
    <blockquote diff:delete="">
      <para>Having regard to the Treaty on the Functioning of the European Union, and in particular Article 114 and Article 168(4)(c) thereof,</para>
      <para>Having regard to the proposal from the European Commission,</para>
      <para>After transmission of the draft legislative act to the national parliaments,</para>
      <para>
        Having regard to the opinion of the European Economic and Social Committee
        <footnote label="1">
          <para>
            Opinion of
            <date>14 February 2013</date>
            (
            <link xlink:href="https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/AUTO/?uri=OJ:C:2013:133:TOC">OJ C 133, 9.5.2013, p. 52</link>
            ).
          </para>
        </footnote>
        ,
      </para>
    </blockquote>
  </preface>
</book>
```

Here's my XSLT:

```xml
    <!--empty template suppresses this attribute-->
    <xsl:template match="@diff:delete[ancestor::*[@name = 'diff:delete']]"/>

    <!--identity template copies everything forward by default-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

My idea was to look for an element that contains the diff:delete attribute, check if it has a parent with the same attribute and apply an empty template in that case. Copy everything else. However, it leaves the original XML intact and does not remove anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
<xsl:template match="@diff:delete[../ancestor::*/@diff:delete]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! Can you help me understand the answer? Doesn't ../ancestor check the parent's parent?

Comment: It looks for an ancestor of the attribute's parent element that has the same attribute. Keep in mind that the parent of the matched attribute is also one of its ancestors. If you do not exclude it, the predicate will always be true.